# ¿como puedo filtrar por fechas para generar un grafico de líneas con matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

hola soy bastante nuevo en python y en ciencia de datos Tambien, así que tengo el siguiente Código en donde tengo una base de datos en la cual están los casos de covid-19 de mi departamento hasta esta fecha

```
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt 

ruta = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/datos punto 6/Casos_positivos_de_Covid-19_en_el_departamento_de_Antioquia.csv',sep = ',',encoding='utf-8-sig')
cambio = ruta.drop(['fecha reporte web','Fecha de notificación','Código DIVIPOLA departamento','Nombre departamento','Código DIVIPOLA municipio','Unidad de medida de edad','Código ISO del país','Nombre del país','Recuperado','Fecha de inicio de síntomas','Fecha de muerte','Fecha de recuperación','Tipo de recuperación','Pertenencia étnica','Nombre del grupo étnico','Ubicación del caso','Estado','Tipo de contagio'], axis=1)
cambio['Fecha de diagnóstico'] = cambio['Fecha de diagnóstico'].apply(lambda x: str(str(x)[0:10]))
cambio['Fecha de diagnóstico'] = pd.to_datetime(cambio['Fecha de diagnóstico'], errors='coerce')
cambio['Fecha de diagnóstico'] = pd.to_datetime(cambio['Fecha de diagnóstico'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

y el output de este Código es algo como lo siguiente:

[image: esta es la tabla de la que tengo que extraer los datos]

lo que necesito hacer es seleccionar los meses del año 2021 y hacer un recuento de los casos por mes para luego generar un grafico de líneas, pero nose como lo hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer, de la siguiente manera. Si las fechas estuvieran como índices del DataFrame, con la sentencia siguiente, se crea una columna, denominada 'Year', que contiene los años.

```
# Extrayendo el año de la columna de índice "Date".
df["Year"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).year
df[:3]
```

En tu caso, el DataFrame se denomina **'cambio'** y la columna con las fechas, **'Fecha de diagnóstico'**. Te recomiendo que cambies el nombre de la columna y pongas el siguiente **'Fecha_de_diagnóstico'**. La sentencia quedaría así.

```
# Extrayendo el año de la columna **'Fecha_de_diagnóstico**'.
cambio["Year"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(cambio.Fecha_de_diagnóstico).year
cambio[:3]
```

Para obtener los meses, haríamos:

```
# Extrayendo el año de la columna **'Fecha_de_diagnóstico'**.
cambio["Month"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(cambio.Fecha_de_diagnóstico).month
cambio[:3]
```

Si no quieres modificar la etiqueta **'Fecha de diagnóstico'**, tendrías que poner, en lugar de  '**cambio.Fecha_de_diagnóstico**', **cambio[Fecha_de_diagnóstico]**.

Si quieres tener las fechas como índice del DataFrame, bastaría con hacer

cambio.set_index('Fecha de diagnóstico', inplace=True).